# Problema con Ajax Recursivo

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

tengo una función ajax la cual es recursiva, lo cual quiere decir, que me devuelve una respuesta y si me devuelve un código la vuelvo a llamar a sí mismo enviando el código que me devolvió, y así hasta que me devuelva en el código el valor de -1, allí finaliza la recursividad.

```js
function actualizarProm (curs_para_mate_prof_codi,peri_dist_codi,es_hija,mensaje,firstTime)
{ var xmlhttp;
 /*Agrego la data*/
 var tabla_info = document.getElementById("tabla_info");
 if (firstTime==1)
  while(tabla_info.rows.length > 1)
   tabla_info.deleteRow(-1);
 var fila = tabla_info.insertRow(-1);
 var cellMensaje = fila.insertCell(0);
 var cellProgreso = fila.insertCell(1);
 cellMensaje.innerHTML = mensaje;
 cellProgreso.innerHTML = '<div id="prog_info_'+peri_dist_codi+'"><img src="../../imagenes/ajax-loader.gif"/></div>';
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("peri_dist_codi", peri_dist_codi);
 var peri_dist_padr_previous = peri_dist_codi;
 data.append("curs_para_mate_prof_codi", curs_para_mate_prof_codi);
 data.append("es_hija", es_hija);
    data.append("opc", "actualizar_prom");
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
   }
   else
   { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
   { document.getElementById('prog_info_'+peri_dist_codi).innerHTML="Finalizado";
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    { obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   if (obj.error == "no" && obj.peri_dist_codi!=-1 && obj.peri_dist_codi!=null)
   { actualizarProm(curs_para_mate_prof_codi,obj.peri_dist_codi,es_hija,obj.mensaje,0);
   }
   else
   { if (obj.error == "no")
    { if (obj.mensaje==null)
      actualizarProm( curs_para_mate_prof_codi, peri_dist_padr_previous, es_hija, "Reintentando", 0 );
     else
     { var fila = tabla_info.insertRow(-1);
      var cellMensaje = fila.insertCell(0);
      var cellProgreso = fila.insertCell(1);
      cellMensaje.innerHTML = obj.mensaje;
      cellProgreso.innerHTML = "Actualización de notas completa";
     }
    }
    else
    { var fila = tabla_info.insertRow(-1);
     var cellMensaje = fila.insertCell(0);
     var cellProgreso = fila.insertCell(1);
     cellMensaje.innerHTML = obj.mensaje;
     cellProgreso.innerHTML = "No se ha completado la actualización de notas, intente nuevamente y luego comunique a sistemas.";
    }
   }
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "script_actualizar_prom.php", false);
   xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

El problema aquí, es que aún cuando el php no me devuelve nada la recursividad se sigue realizando. Es decir, cómo podría hacer que espere hasta que el server responda y allí continúe con la siguiente recursidad, y así no se quede ciclado. Porque lo que está en la línea

```js
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

no funciona, ya que entra así sea que aún no me haya devuelto nada el php. En el archivo php llamo a un procedimiento almacenado el cual se ejecuta y demora un poco.
Espero me hayan entendido. Gracias por su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: En realidad, creo que no deberías aplicar llamadas recursivas al servidor porque impacta duramente en rendimiento. En todo caso, sería mejor que esas llamadas recursivas se realizen de lado del servidor para cumplir con la funcionalidad que necesitas.

Comment: Y cómo podría lograr lo que me dices, me podrías dar un indicio. Gracias.

Comment: Pues para eso tendríamos que ver la implementación del método en el servidor, es decir, tu código PHP que atiende este servicio. Luego, comprender qué es lo que quieres lograr y encontrar la mejor manera para ello.

Answer (score 1):

Es raro lo que te está pasando. Con el if:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

se está logrando seguro que entre ahí solo en el caso que la conexión haya terminado (`redyState==4`) y que no haya dado error (`status==200`).

Además lo siguiente que tiene que ocurrir es que se reciba una respuesta en formato JSON (si no `obj` no existiría y no se podría controlar y no entraría en la recursión.

Podrías agregar un `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` antes de la sentencia:

```
actualizarProm(curs_para_mate_prof_codi,obj.peri_dist_codi,es_hija,obj.mensaje,0);
```

para ver qué está pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error lo tenes en donde agregas la funcion recursiva del ajax.

Segun los docs lo tenes que tomar en `onload()`

```
function reqExito () {
   obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   if (obj.error == "no" && ...) { 
         actualizarProm(curs_para_mate_prof_codi,obj....,0);
          ...
    }
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqExito;
oReq.open("POST", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```

Igualmente te recomiendo usar JQuery. Puede ser que no puedas, pero tu codigo quedaria mucho mas prolijo:

```
$.post("script_actualizar_prom.php", function (data) { 
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if (obj.error == "no" && ...) { 
          actualizarProm(curs_para_mate_prof_codi,obj.peri_dist_codi,es_hija,obj.mensaje,0);
          ...
     }
 })
```